# reordering list items - cut li element and insert after li:first-child

Tags: jquery, css

I can't seem to work this out...

I need to detach (or remove) a selected list element, and insert it back into the ul *after* the first li element.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/PgfEF/

So i thought this might work, but no;

```
$(this).slice().prependTo('ul.support-items > li:first-child:after');
```

any help appreciated,
thanks Cam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('ul.support-items li').click(function(){
    $(this).insertAfter('ul.support-items li:first');
})​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PgfEF/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this
    `$this.slice().after('ul.support-items');`

Comment: no luck, it adds text to the DOM rather than the list element.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(this).parent().prepend($(this).detach());
```

Comment: thanks, but that adds it to the beginning. i need it after the first-child. think i managed to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

worked out a solution, not elegant, but it works..

http://fiddle.jshell.net/PgfEF/1/